# setting MisFire instruction in quartz

Tags: c#, quartz.net, misfire-instruction

i am trying to set Misfire instruction to ignore the missed triggers

```
   <object id="RunSchedulerJobTrigger" type="Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.CronTriggerObject, Spring.Scheduling.Quartz, Version=1.2.0.23130, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07">
            <property name="jobDetail" ref="RunSchedulerJob" />

            <property name="cronExpressionString" value="0 30 0 * * ?"/>
            <!-- Value is a Cron String (0-Seconds[0-59] 30-Minutes[0-59] 0-hours[0-23] * * ?) means, Fire everyday at 12:30AM -->
            **<property name="misfireInstructionName" value="IgnoreMisfirePolicy"/>**

        </object>
```

but getting an error which says

Error creating object with name 'RunSchedulerJobTrigger' defined in 'file [D:\Configuration\AppContext.xml] line 17' : Initialization of object failed : Unknown field 'IgnoreMisfirePolicy' ---> System.Exception: Unknown field 'IgnoreMisfirePolicy'
   at Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.Constants.AsNumber(String field)
   at Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.CronTriggerObject.set_MisfireInstructionName(String value)
   at Spring.Expressions.PropertyOrFieldNode.SetPropertyOrFieldValue(Object context, EvaluationContext evalContext, Object newValue)
   at Spring.Expressions.PropertyOrFieldNode.Set(Object context, EvaluationContext evalContext, Object newValue)
   at Spring.Objects.ObjectWrapper.SetPropertyValues(IPropertyValues propertyValues, Boolean ignoreUnknown)
   at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.ApplyPropertyValues(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper, IPropertyValues propertie...

Answer (score 0):

I tried similar configuration and couldn't reproduce with Spring.NET 1.3.2 code base. I dug to older revisions inside old CVS repository and it seems that this was a bug in earlier version (1.2? - that seems to be the version you are using) and [has been since fixed](http://springnet.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/springnet/Spring.Net.Integration/projects/Spring.Scheduling.Quartz/src/Spring/Spring.Scheduling.Quartz/Scheduling/Quartz/CronTriggerObject.cs?r1=1.2&r2=1.3&) (actually over six years ago, oh how the time flies).

I would suggest you try out the latest 1.3.2 version and see if it solves your problem.